# How to change navbar background colour after scrolling past full screen background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the navbar background color change to black when it reaches the end of the full screen background image. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I've tried a lot and eventually got pointed to [this post](https://codepen.io/rama-krishna-the-selector/pen/GemNrB) which shows the navbar at least changing color on scroll, so I took that code and modify it but it is not working. If someone could quickly write up the most basic code to make the navbar disappear after scrolling the full screen background image, that would be amazing and I would be extremely grateful, thank you.
The snippet shows what I have at the moment:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it 
takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1200, function(){
   
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click 
behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#infoweb1").show();
$("#infoweb2").hide();
$("#infoweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#infoweb1").hide();
$("#infoweb2").show();
$("#infoweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#infoweb1").hide();
$("#infoweb2").hide();
$("#infoweb3").show();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#infotext1").show();
$("#infotext2").hide();
$("#infotext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#infotext1").hide();
$("#infotext2").show();
$("#infotext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#infowebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#infotext1").hide();
$("#infotext2").hide();
$("#infotext3").show();
});
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#articleweb1").show();
$("#articleweb2").hide();
$("#articleweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#articleweb1").hide();
$("#articleweb2").show();
$("#articleweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#articleweb1").hide();
$("#articleweb2").hide();
$("#articleweb3").show();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#articletext1").show();
$("#articletext2").hide();
$("#articletext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#articletext1").hide();
$("#articletext2").show();
$("#articletext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#articlewebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#articletext1").hide();
$("#articletext2").hide();
$("#articletext3").show();
});
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#blogweb1").show();
$("#blogweb2").hide();
$("#blogweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#blogweb1").hide();
$("#blogweb2").show();
$("#blogweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#blogweb1").hide();
$("#blogweb2").hide();
$("#blogweb3").show();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#blogtext1").show();
$("#blogtext2").hide();
$("#blogtext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#blogtext1").hide();
$("#blogtext2").show();
$("#blogtext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#blogwebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#blogtext1").hide();
$("#blogtext2").hide();
$("#blogtext3").show();
});
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#photoweb1").show();
$("#photoweb2").hide();
$("#photoweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#photoweb1").hide();
$("#photoweb2").show();
$("#photoweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#photoweb1").hide();
$("#photoweb2").hide();
$("#photoweb3").show();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#phototext1").show();
$("#phototext2").hide();
$("#phototext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#phototext1").hide();
$("#phototext2").show();
$("#phototext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#photowebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#phototext1").hide();
$("#phototext2").hide();
$("#phototext3").show();
});
});



$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#ecomweb1").show();
$("#ecomweb2").hide();
$("#ecomweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#ecomweb1").hide();
$("#ecomweb2").show();
$("#ecomweb3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#ecomweb1").hide();
$("#ecomweb2").hide();
$("#ecomweb3").show();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle1").click(function(){
$("#ecomtext1").show();
$("#ecomtext2").hide();
$("#ecomtext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle2").click(function(){
$("#ecomtext1").hide();
$("#ecomtext2").show();
$("#ecomtext3").hide();
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ecomwebstyle3").click(function(){
$("#ecomtext1").hide();
$("#ecomtext2").hide();
$("#ecomtext3").show();
});
});
```

```css
/* KEYFRAMES START */

@keyframes slideInDown {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInDown {
 animation-name: slideInDown;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
 0%  {opacity: 0;}
 10%  {opacity: 0.1;}
 20%  {opacity: 0.2;}
 30%  {opacity: 0.3;}
 40%  {opacity: 0.4;}
 50%  {opacity: 0.5;}
 60%  {opacity: 0.6;}
 70%  {opacity: 0.7;}
 80%  {opacity: 0.8;}
 90%  {opacity: 0.9;}
 100% {opacity: 1;}

}

.fadeIn {
 animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInRight {
  animation-name: slideInRight;
}

@keyframes jackInTheBox {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.1) rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }

  70% {
    transform: rotate(3deg);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.jackInTheBox {
  animation-name: jackInTheBox;
}

/* KEYFRAMES END */





/* NAVBAR START */

.navbar {
 height:90px;
 color:white;
}

.nav-link {
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 background-color:transparent;
}

#logo {
 width:175px;
 height:65px;
 border: 1px solid white;
}



li::after {
 background-color: white;
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

li:hover::after {
 width: 100%;
 left:0%;
 animation-name: fadeIn;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-duration: 300ms;
}

.nav-item {
 animation-name: slideInDown;
 animation-duration: 800ms;
 animation-delay: 0s;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight:100;
}

li {
 position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center {     /* Centers navbar items to the middle */
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.navbar-nav > li{   /* Creates space between items in navbar */
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-right:30px;
}

.navbar-brand {
 animation-name: slideInDown;
 animation-duration: 800ms;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}

.navbar a {
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-radius: 8px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

/* NAVBAR END */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Roboto:100|Work+Sans:100,300|Kalam:300|Coming+Soon|Quicksand:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/camwiegert/in-view/master/dist/in-view.min.js">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stackoverflow.css"> <!-- This css file is prioritised over any others below it -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <title>Home | Business</title>
 

<!-- Script Start -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script End -->
</head>



<body>

<span id="home"></span>


<!-- Navbar Start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-transparent navbar-light">

<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNav">
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-center"> 

  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#home" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><b>HOME</b></a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutus" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><b>ABOUT US</b></a>
  </li>
  
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#features" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><b>FEATURES</b></a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#templates" style="padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;"><b>EXAMPLE </b></a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</div>

</nav>
<!-- Navbar End -->
```

I have also created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZeGgP).

Comment: What's the status of your issue ? Did our solutions help at all ?

Comment: Yes, thank you all so much... sorry, I completely forgot to thank you when I tried the solution

Comment: Then mark an answer as the solution if you can @Josh

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS & Jquery

```
.navbar-light.black-bg{
  background:#000 !important;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 300) {
        $(".navbar").addClass('black-bg');
    } else {
        $(".navbar").removeClass("black-bg");
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROgeLO

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lalji's answer I would modify the proposed JS to add the class once the div (`.view` here) height's has been scrolled (minus the `.navbar`'s height). I would add a background transition to `.navbar` as well for a smooth experience.

JS :

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= $('.view').height() - 90) {
           $(".navbar").addClass('black-bg');
      } else {
           $(".navbar").removeClass("black-bg");
      }
 });
```

CSS :

```
 .navbar {
      transition: background 1s; /* Change 1s to the wanted duration */
 }
```

Available as a fork of Lalji's pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRweeB).